Add a button on elementor add new section in edit page
I want to add a button in elementor add new section on edit page. In my plugin root file I just enqueued the js file only. I ensured that the js file was loaded perfectly and in console I can see at last this console.log('Elementor initialized');. If anyone can solve the issue please help me. For clarification, I just want to add a button only.
See the image for more clear 
    console.log('custom-button.js loaded');

jQuery(window).on('elementor:init', function() {
    console.log('Elementor initialized');

    elementor.hooks.addAction('editor/init', function() {
        console.log('Editor initialized');

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const targetContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-add-new-section, .e-view');

            console.log('Checking for target containers:', targetContainers);

            if (targetContainers.length > 0) {
                targetContainers.forEach((container, index) => {
                    console.log(`Container ${index} found`, container);
                    
                    if (container.classList.contains('e-view')) {
                        const buttonDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        buttonDiv.classList.add('elementor-add-section-area-button');

                        const newButton = document.createElement('button');
                        newButton.textContent = 'Add New Section';
                        newButton.classList.add('button', 'button-primary');

                        buttonDiv.appendChild(newButton);
                        container.appendChild(buttonDiv);
                        console.log('Button added to the editor');

                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log('No matching target containers found yet');
            }
        }, 500); 
    });
});


Can you provide a minimal reproducible example embedded into your question as a snippet? We need 1. A small piece of HTML, 2. A small piece of CSS, 3. A small piece of Javascript, 4. The HTML of the button you want to add, 5. Explanation about when and how you want the button to be added. Thanks!

as like happy addons, elements pack, essential addons
